# non-key join with GlobalTable vs Ktable-Ktable Join?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am quite curious as to why a non-key join works with **GlobalKTtable** vs **KTable-KTable** ? Although I understand why we don't need co-partitioning for a `globalKTable (BroadCast Join)`, I don't not understand what enable the non-key join with it ? Can anyone, give a rough idea of what is happening ?

Comment: Supporting non-key KTable-KTable joins is WIP: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-213+Support+non-key+joining+in+KTable

Comment: Yes I know :) ! What I am trying to understand is why is it possible with a globalktable. What is the difference ...

Comment: See my comment below: for stream-globalKtable joins, the join still used the primary key of the GlobalKTable -- the non-key part is from the stream...

Comment: My bad I see. However what makes it feasible with a globalktable and not with Kstream-kstream ?? I know it is detail, but it is very helpful to have a sense of what is going on ... to better understand how to use the lib

Comment: So far the Kstream-kstream does not support non-key join either ....

Comment: For KStream-KStream you don't really need it. You can just do a `streamA.selectKey(...).join(streamB,...)`. Because record streams are immutable facts and the join is windowed, it's semantically quite different compared to table joins. KStream-KStream joins are n:m joins anyway. However, KTable-KTable joins are primary key 1:1 joins atm, and KIP-213 adds 1:n joins. -- Because KTables have update semantics and the notion of a primary key, you cannot just re-key the table as you can do for streams to do a 1:n join...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I’ll keep wrapping my head around those, until I’m fully comfortable with the api and what happens under the hood and those comments of your really helped. Thanks

Comment: Sure. This may help, too: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlobalKTable & KTable, both represent the abstraction of changelog, but the difference is KTable is created locally for each application instance for each partition while GlobalKTable is populated with the entire data from all the partitions on each application instance. It copies whole data on each application instance that means entire dataset is available for querying on each instance. Hence it doesn't require co-partitioning and the lookups are possible in the entire table.

In the below example :

```
KStream<String, Long> left = ...;  // // KStream has string type key
GlobalKTable<Integer, Double> right = ...;   // GlobalKTable has integer type key

// Java 8+ example, using lambda expressions
KStream<String, String> joined = left.leftJoin(right,
    (leftKey, leftValue) -> leftKey.length(), /* derive a (potentially) new key by which to lookup against the table */
    (leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue /* ValueJoiner */
  );
```

Select a key from the left stream using KeyValueMapper which you can use to lookup in GlobalKTable as given below:

```
(leftKey, leftValue) -> leftKey.length(), /* select a (potentially) new key by which to lookup against the table */
```

GlobalKTable are convenient for joins but expensive as it requires more storage as compared to KTables and also increases the network & kafka broker load.

Comment: I still don’t get what enable the ability to look into all the fields ??? What is it that is missing in the KTable-KTable scenario that does not allow to look or join in non-key fiels (roughly). I understand the co-partitioning issue, but this to me is not explicitly related to the non-key field issue ... else could you surface it a bit more please ...

Comment: If you go to  [KStreamImpl](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/99737588b6db7647d0d03b7306f143714fbae4d5/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamImpl.java#L946) link, you can see how it works. keyMapper selects the key for GlobalKTable i.e. K2 and KStreamKTableJoinProcessor process method shows how valueGetter is used to get the record having key "k2".

Comment: Note, that the non-key part in the join if for the _stream_: you extract an attribute from the stream record value, and do a lookup into the table (using the key of the table). It's not supported atm, to have a non-key attribute from the table.